# Fix indent for section title

Tags: sectioning, indentation, memoir, titlesec

I like to recreate the layout of an official template, in order to get rid of Word. Because the template is from the government, I must recreate it 1:1.

In the end, the document should look like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.

1.      First Section Title
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.

1.1     First Subsection Title
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.

1.1.1   First Subsubsection Title
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.
```

My main problem is the spacing between the section numbers and the titles. All section titles must begin on a fixed indent defined by the template, so the spacing between the numbers and the titles must be dynamic. With plain latex and `titlesec` I was only able to specify a fixed space. I also tried the `memoir` package with `hangsecnum`, but with this option the numbers will be aligned left, also with a fixed space between the section numbers and the title.

Would it be possible to give me a hint how to create such a layout?

Comment: Could you please provide a few more specifics regarding papersize (a4?, usletter?, ...), width and height of text block on page, the amount of indent (1.5cm?, 1inch?, ...), the appearance of the (subsub,sub)section headers (same font size as text? same font weight as text, or boldface and/or italics?), and the amount of spacing above and below sectioning headers?

Comment: You might also want to consider cmhughes's solution to my question: ["How can I align section titles and list environments in the left margin?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33137/how-can-i-align-section-titles-and-list-environments-in-the-left-margin)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172446/430

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) as follows:

```
\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{titlesec}%
\titleformat{\section} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\makebox[3em][l]{\itshape\thesection}}{1em}{}%
\titleformat{\subsection} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\makebox[3em][l]{\itshape\thesubsection}}{1em}{}%
\titleformat{\subsubsection} {\normalfont\bfseries}{\makebox[3em][l]{\itshape\thesubsubsection}}{1em}{}%

\addtolength{\leftskip}{\widthof{\normalfont\bfseries\makebox[4em]{}}}% Indent text
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newlength{\texthanging}
\setlength{\texthanging}{2cm}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\protect\makebox[0pt][r]{%
  \protect\makebox[\texthanging][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname.}}}
%\def\@seccntformat#1{\llap{\hbox to\texthanging{
%  \csname the#1\endcsname.\hfil}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\hanging{\leftskip=\texthanging}
\newcommand\nohanging{\leftskip=0pt }

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.

\hanging

\section{First Section Title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.

\subsection{First Subsection Title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.

\subsubsection{First Subsubsection Title}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.

\nohanging

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata.

\end{document}
```

The uncommented and the commented versions of `\@seccntformat` are equivalent, but the commented version uses low level commands.