# Subsection, subsubsection, etc. title outside (left of) the subsection, subsubsection, etc. content block

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, minipage

How could I get subsections, subsubsections, paragraphs, and subparagraphs (which I'll call "sections" from now on) that look like the one in [this PDF file](http://wftda.com/rules/wftda-rules.pdf) ?

In this PDF example, the indentation between one level of section and the next is too much, but the important point I would like to keep is that **the name of the section** (actually only its numbering) **is detached to the left** and the **section content consists of one block to the right**.

I guess there are some *minipages* involved, but i'm not sure how to use them to get the right result.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This can probably be done using the `titlesec` package; something that sounds quite similar: [How can I align section titles and list environments in the left margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33138)

Comment: This looks like one giant iterated enumerate environment. You can certainly use `enumitem` to get the spacings and the numbering as desired. And probably also the decoration of the first level titles.

Comment: ... however the table of contents will then need to be created in some other way.

Comment: I've read the whole doc of titlesec, and apparently nothing seems to be able to do what i want... (since i'm a latex beginner, it's fairly likely that i missed something obvious).
In the topic you mentionned, @cmhughes the use of \llap is a good idea, so the only thing i now need is the capability to indent a whole paragraph and not only its first line.

Comment: @jfbu , maybe i could do this with a giant enum, but i have a whole bunch of \label + \ref throughout the document and i don't know at all how to have a reference to an enum item (with the corresponding numbering).

Answer (score 1):

Using `enumitem` will get you some way towards your goal. One would have to add some extra coding to get automatically a TOC though.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*.}
\begin{document}

\begin{legal}
\item Rule 1
  \begin{legal}
  \item Subrule
    \begin{legal}
      \item a
      \item \label{hello}b
      \item c
    \end{legal}
  \item Subrule 
    \begin{legal}
      \item a
      \item b
      \item \label{world}c
    \end{legal}
  \end{legal}
\item Rule 2
  \begin{legal}
  \item Subrule
    \begin{legal}
      \item a
      \item b
      \item c
    \end{legal}
  \item Subrule 
    \begin{legal}
      \item a
      \item b
      \item c
    \end{legal}
  \end{legal}
\end{legal}

the hello label has number \ref{hello}

the world label has number \ref{world}
\end{document}
```

[image: legal list]