# Heading number in margin using titlesec and/or komascript

Tags: sectioning, indentation, koma-script, titlesec

Using `titlesec` and/or `komascript` how do I format all headings so the number is **left aligned** in the margin, the title to the right, with a horizontal rule underneath it all (from margin to text width edge).

What's left of my hair is about to come out :(

```
 _____________________________
|                             |
| 3.1  Section Title          |
| -------------------------   |
|      Text width paragraph   |
|      Blah blah blah blah    |
|                             |

  >-<  >------------------<
   |                |
   `-- Margin       ` Text
```

Comment: have you seen [Theorem Name/Numbering in Margin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59244) or [How can I align section titles and list environments in the left margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33137) you should be able to adapt it to include `titlerule` which will give you the horizontal line...

Comment: @cmhughes yes (and many more similar answers), but I haven't found anything that does left alignment and horizontal rule.  I'm still working on it, just hoping a guru will through me a bone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one possibility using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in+\hoffset\relax}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\llap{\hspace*{-\mylen}\thesection\hfill}}{0em}{}
  [{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{%
    \hspace*{-\mylen}\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+\mylen\relax}{1pt}}}]

\begin{document}

\section{A Test Section with a Short Title}
\lipsum[4]
\section{A Test Section with a Long Title Spanning More than One Line}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can adjust the value for `\mylen` to get the desired positioning for the numbers; for example, using

```
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+\hoffset\relax}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: To understand your answer better, would you kindly elaborate how your solution works (except the rule part)?

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: margin box size for number is not dynamic.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,letterpaper,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]%
  {\normalfont\scshape\filright}%
  {\makebox[2em][l]{\thesection}}%
  {1em}
  {}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{-3em}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem Ipsem}
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also consider using `\titlespacing*{...}` if you wish to prevent the paragraph following the section from being indented.