# Location of the numeration in the text

Tags: sectioning, lyx, margins

I been looking to see how to put the location of the numeration of the different sections to one side of the margin, something like this.

[image]

As you can see the numeration is "before" of the beginning of the margin. Is that possible in lyx?

Comment: For a suggestion on what kind of magic to put in your preamble, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98272/heading-number-in-margin-using-titlesec-and-or-komascript

Answer (score 1):

Look for the enumitem package's document in your PC. It's a specific package for list alteration. OK?

Comment: You might expand your answer with some example code etc. to make it even better :-)

Comment: The question is about section-related headings, not lists.

Comment: He should use the enumitem packagem for it. Just think about that. It's possible.