# titlesec: right-justified section number in margin

Tags: sectioning, margins, titlesec

I’ve been using the following code snipped (I can’t remember where I found it) to put right-justified section numbers into the left margin:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\protect\makebox[0pt][r]{\csname
      the#1\endcsname\hspace{6pt}}} \makeatother
```

However, I've started using `titlesec` to customise the layout of section headings, and the code above no longer works for any section heading styles I've defined using `titlesec`. For example, here I define `\titleformat` for subsections, but not sections or subsubsections:

[image]

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98272) shows how to put section numbers into the left margin using `\titlesec`, but with left-justified number placement. How do I do this while retaining the right-justified format of the `\@seccntformat` definition above?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\protect\makebox[0pt][r]{\csname
      the#1\endcsname\hspace{6pt}}} \makeatother

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.5}%
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should maybe specify for which levels you want this to apply.

Comment: I’d like to apply this to all levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the example, I took the standard definitions for sectional titles from the documentation of `titlesec` (section 9.2) and changed `1em` to `0pt`, adding `\marginsecnumber` in front of each counter representation command.

Add your own customizations.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\marginsecnumber}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#1\hspace{6pt}}%
}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\marginsecnumber\thesection}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}
  {\marginsecnumber\thesubsection}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\marginsecnumber\thesubsubsection}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\marginsecnumber\theparagraph}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\marginsecnumber\thesubparagraph}
  {0pt}
  {}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.5}%
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

I propose this variant layout, where all ((sub)sub)sections numbers are in the margin and have the same vertical axis, with the `eqparbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\llap{\eqmakebox[S]{\thesection}}}{\marginparsep}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-\marginparsep}{*3.25}{*1.5}%
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\llap{\eqmakebox[S]{\thesubsection}}}{\marginparsep}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-\marginparsep}{*3.5}{*2.3}%

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\llap{\eqmakebox[S]{\thesubsubsection}}}{\marginparsep}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-\marginparsep}{*3.25}{*1.5}%

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `\llap`, taken from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59244):

[image]

If you want the section and subsubsection numbers to align properly with the subsection numbers, define `\titleformat` for those headings as well, and drop the use of `\@seccntformat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\protect\makebox[0pt][r]{\csname
      the#1\endcsname\hspace{6pt}}} \makeatother

\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{\llap{\thesubsection\hskip 9pt}}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.5}%
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that by default `\subsection` uses a `\large` font (your answer changes that to the normal size).

Comment: @Skillmon Fixed, thanks!