# How to get chapter title better aligned?

Tags: spacing, chapters

this question : [Margins of Section Title is Out of Bounds](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195885/margins-of-section-title-is-out-of-bounds) unfortunately does not help me. 
When I run the bottom code, the top line is shorter than the bottom which seems awkward in documents where all lines are filled with the exception of the bottom line of each paragraph.
Do you have any idea how I get that spacing issue right?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hope}

\section{Hope of the Essential Trigonometry TRIGTEST exogenous endogenous treetop}
\blindtext

\section{Hope of the Essential Trigonometry TRIGOTEST}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you change the layout (margins, etc.) or the wording, or the font, or if you don't want to change any of these, then you have to accept something unusual. If you accept giving up on the raggedright titles and hyphenating TRIGTEST in them, you can do this:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hope}

\section{Hope of the Essential Trigonometry TRIG\-TEST exogenous endogenous treetop}
\blindtext

\section{Hope of the Essential Trigonometry TRIGOTEST}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]