# How to make section title text align with paragraph indentation?

Tags: sectioning, indentation

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26905/430

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An option using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec); the idea is to place the counter inside a box of width equal to the value for `\parindent`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\parindent{30pt}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\parindent}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\makebox[\mylen][l]{\thesection.}}
  {0pt}
  {}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Most probably you won't need the line

```
\setlength\parindent{30pt}
```

I used it in my example code to have a generous value for `\parindent`, which apparently your class already provides. Since your class seems to be a non-standard one (seeing the font size for section titles), please consider changing the `\Large` in the second mandatory argument of

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\makebox[\mylen][l]{\thesection.}}
  {0pt}
  {}
```

to conform to your class definitions.